Make a specific div element go down a bit
I need 2 div elements in my code to go down a slight bit, both of them
                <div class="username-and-timestamp">
                    <div class="username">RandomDude</div>
                    <div class="timestamp">17 minutes ago.</div>
                </div>

I've tried to use margin style on username-and-timestamp and also line-height, both did not work!
heres my css:
Heres my full code:
(CSS)
:root {
    --primary: #161720;
    --primary-lightened: #2A2B35;
}

html {
    background-color: var(--primary)
}

.post {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    background-color: var(--primary-lightened);
    position: relative;
}

.third-line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 2.5px;
    background-color: var(--primary);
    /* Change this to the color you want */
}

.username {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.timestamp {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: gray;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.info {
    padding-left: 65px;
}

.profile-picture {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 10px;
}

.badge {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: auto;
}


.post-text {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Mukta", sans-serif;
    padding: 20px;
    /* Add this line */
    display: block;
    /* Add this line */
}

.post-actions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    /* This will space the icons evenly */
    color: white;
    /* This will make the icons white */
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    /* Add this line */
}

.post-actions i:hover {
    color: pink;
    /* This will make the icons pink on hover */
}

.number {
    font-size: 16.5px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
}

I tried the line height and the margin property, did not work.
The way i tried the margin property was:
.username-and-timestamp {
    margin-bottom: (...)px;
}

Any number of pixels did not work. (even negative values).
.username-and-timestamp {
    line-height: (...)px;
}

Same here, Any number of pixels did not work. (even negative values).
My html:
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/main/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='/scripts/main/main.js') }}"></script>
    <title>User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mukta:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <body>
        <div class="post">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="avatar-container">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" alt="Profile Picture"
                        class="profile-picture">
                    <img class="badge"
                        src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1191384595938164766/1224995524910907392/mod_badge.png?ex=661f84fc&is=660d0ffc&hm=e810c73ddf07d60a369ed7814135bdb7a59bb4be3edc32c6fd8891705967a0bb&"
                        alt="Badge" title="This post was made by an admin.">
                </div>
                <div class="username-and-timestamp">
                    <div class="username">RandomDude</div>
                    <div class="timestamp">17 minutes ago.</div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="third-line"></div>
            <div class="post-content">
                <!-- Sample Content -->
                <span class="post-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                    Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
                    a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
                    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
                    more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
                    Ipsum.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="post-actions">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"><span class="number"> 7221</span></i>
                <i class="fa fa-share"><span class="number"> 106</span></i>
            </div>
    </body>

</body>

</html>```

Changing any of those values moves the entire post down


Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i think you want to use margin-top instead of margin-bottom

Hi himansu, that moves my entire post up/down! I want to move the text only down

hey paulie, I've added some more clarification.

why not try to add margin-bottom/top to the .username class and .timestamp class separately? E.g. .username { margin-top: 5px; }

Hi @TanishqS, The username moves, butt he timestamp just completely refuses to move, ive tried everything but the username just does not move (I've tried the solution you've mentioned too.)

why not try to add margin-top: 5px !important;

Also add an image of the developer tools getting the CSS of the element you are trying to move to better understand your problem

div class post gives "this element is causing an element to overflow."
this is the css:
.username {
  margin-top: 15px !important;
}
.username {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
:root {
  --primary: #161720;
  --primary-lightened: #2A2B35;
}```

is transform : translateY() an option?

@coolguy: you are welcome :) but keep in mind, that transform also handles rotation, scaling a.s.o. in the same property, which thus overrides existing values - so try to use variables here ;)     > transform: var(--allDifferentTransformations)

In my opinion there are two ways to go about this.

You can use .username-and-timestamp { padding-top:(..)px; }  after your timestamp element to move the container a bit lower
You can use .username, .timestamp { padding-top:5px; }  to give both elements (username and timestamp) a padding of 5pχ for example thus making them both go down a bit but also create 5px distance between them. Hope i helped!


It's better to try margin-top first. Because padding doesn't move the element itself rather creates clear space inside this container between container's border and it's content (eg. child container). Using padding can lead to unintended container representation (border, background, etc.)
